# Error while doing "npm install"

Tags: git, node.js, heroku, npm

I am new to this. I do not know if this has to be taken seriously or I can proceed with what I am upto. Only here I can post it with full detail.

```
npm ERR! error installing express@3.3.5
npm ERR! error rolling back express@3.3.5 Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/home/ubuntu/vengit/node_modules/express'

npm ERR! Unsupported
npm ERR! Not compatible with your version of node/npm: connect@2.8.5
npm ERR! Required: {"node":">= 0.8.0"}
npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.1.4","node":"0.6.12"}
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-40-virtual
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/vengit
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! message Unsupported
npm ERR! errno {}
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/keypress
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/vengit/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Comment: You have Node 0.6.12, you won't be able to install Express 3.x.x. Why can't you upgrade Node.js? Is there any specific reason to be with 0.6.12?

Comment: No. There is no reason. Let me try upgrading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because one of Express' dependencies ([Connect](https://npmjs.org/package/connect)) requires Node 0.8.0 or later.

```
npm ERR! Required: {"node":">= 0.8.0"}
npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.1.4","node":"0.6.12"}
```

And, since you have Node 0.6.12 installed, you won't be able to install Express 3.3.5.

You can try to install an older version of Express or update Node to at least 0.8.0.